# Google Apps Script Forms Service seems to have undocumented automatic text correction

Tags: google-apps-script, settitle

I have some Apps Script code in a Google Sheet which uses the Forms Service to create a Google Form.  The required text for each of the Google Form questions in held in a tab on the Sheet called "Questions".

In the required text of one option of a multiple choice question, my customer inadvertently put two space characters between two words instead of one space character. The cell in the Questions tab therefore contained the double-space.

However, when the Google Form was then created the Forms Service automatically corrected the double space of the original required text into a single space, which went into the Form (possibly done in the setTitle Method).

This means that, when the Form Response from the user was post-processed, the text returned from that option contained a single space, whereas the original text for that option was double spaced.

So when post-processing checked the user response text against the original text, the comparison failed due to Forms Service auto-correcting the double space.

I have not found any documentation about this automatic correction function of the Forms Service.  Does anyone know where I might find such documentation, and does Forms Service automatically correct for anything else ?

All help most gratefully received.

Merry Christmas !

Thanks Richard

PS The post-processing is complex and confidential. Suffice to say that in part I need to check multiple choice responses against the original text.

Comment: A [mcve] does not suggest that it be your actual code but rather just a piece of code that reproduces the same problem.  So confidentiality does not prevent you from posting such a piece of code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `(possibly done in the setTitle Method).` I think this is unlikely if only because you said an _option_ value contained the leading spaces. OTOH, I manually created a form with an option value with leading spaces. Forms accepted the value and did not "remove" the spaces but... in "viewform" the leading spaces were not displayed nor were they passed to Google Sheets when selected; in "edit" mode, the Form continues to retain the leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Providing the code is tricky due to its size and the confidentiality issue.  But now I have an issue, I will do a test version, cut it right down and see exactly where this space removal occurs.  Then I can post.

Also the use of double spaces was in the middle of text, not leading spaces (though that is another case I should consider).


Merry Christmas
Richard